# More activities with registerReceiver

Tags: android

I've an application with several activities. Every activities register a `broadcastReceiver` and, in the overrided method `onStop`, I unregister it. When I execute this (part of) method in Main activity:

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

in Home activity, when the method `broadcastReciverMethod` recive the broadcast message, the application throw an exception. I've added a Log in `broadcastReciverMethod` in each activity and what I get is that a log row that came from the Main activity (unexpected).

How I can resolve it?

**UPDATE**
In my case, the unregister method must be called in `onStop` method because I use a vocal recogniter that set the activity in pause state

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your post and indicate at what code line the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not advisable to unregister your receiver in onStop method.......Best practice is to register receiver in onResume method and unregister receiver in onPause method......Hope that solves your problem!